# Wierd react props error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-5

I have two react components:

```
var AllMeals = React.createClass({
        getInitialState() {
          return { meals: [], current_page: 0, total_pages: 0, total_count: 0}
        },

        componentDidMount() {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/api/v2/meals',
            headers: window.Auth.retrieveData('authHeaders'),
            success: (data, status, request) => {
             this.setState({ meals: data,
               current_page: request.getResponseHeader('X-Page'),
               total_pages: request.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Pages'),
               total_count: request.getResponseHeader('X-Total')});
            }
           });
        },

        render() {
          const meals = this.state.meals;
          return (
          <div>
            <MealList meals={meals} />
          </div>
          )
        }
});

module.exports = AllMeals
```

and

```
 var MealList = React.createClass({
        getInitialState() {
          console.log(this.props)
          return { meals: this.props.meals }
        },

        handleSubmit(meal) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'api/v2/meals',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: window.Auth.retrieveData('authHeaders'),
            data: {name: meal.name, calories: meal.calories, meal_time: meal.meal_time, meal_date: meal.meal_date},
            success: (new_meal) => {
              newState = this.state.meals.concat(new_meal);
              this.setState({ meals: newState })
            },
            error: (response) => {
              console.log(response)
            }
          })
        },

        filterMeals(id) {
          var newState = this.state.meals.filter((meal) => {
            return meal.id != id;
          });
          this.setState({ meals: newState})
        },

        handleUpdate(meal) {
          var meals = this.state.meals;
          $.ajax({
            url: `api/v2/meals/${meal.id}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: {name: meal.name, calories: meal.calories, meal_time: meal.meal_time, meal_date: meal.meal_date},
            headers: window.Auth.retrieveData('authHeaders'),
            success: (new_meal) => {
              this.setState({
                meals: meals.map(meal => meal.id === new_meal.id ? new_meal : meal)
              })
            },
            error: (response) => {
              console.log(response);
            }
          });
        },


        handleDelete(id) {
          $.ajax({
            url: `api/v2/meals/${id}`,
            type: 'DELETE',
            headers: window.Auth.retrieveData('authHeaders'),
            success: (response) => {
              this.filterMeals(id);
            },
            error: (response) => {
              console.log(response);
            }
          });
        },

        handleSearch(meals) {
          this.setState({ meals : [...meals] })
        },

        render() {  
          const mealsMarkup = this.state.meals.map((meal) => {
            return (
              <Meal key={meal.id} {...meal} handleDelete={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)} />
            )
          });

          return (
          <div>
            <div className="col-lg-9">
                <div className="page-header">
                    <h2>Meals</h2>
                </div>
              <div className='table-responsive'>
              <table className='table'>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Meal</th>
                    <th>Calories</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {mealsMarkup}
                   <MealForm handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} buttonText='Add Meal' />
                </tbody>
              </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <MealFilterForm handleSubmit={this.handleSearch} />
          </div>
          )
        }
 });

 module.exports = MealList;
```

Weirdly `this.props.meals` in `MealList` is empty. Yes, I checked if meals array exists on `AllMeals`. What could be wrong?

Comment: Isn't `getInitialState` is called before your ajax done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are only using the props in `MealList` before the Ajax call is done, (`getInitialState` is not called when re-rendered). **You should set the state again when the props change** with `componentWillReceiveProps()` in `MealList` or use the props directly.

Probably adding something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    meals: nextProps.meals
  });
}
```

should be enough.